# Javafx saving the state of the scene in a game

Tags: javafx

I am developing a game with nodes and edges. The scenes are developed in scenebuilder. During the game user selects the node and the node color changes to red. After that a new scene has to be opened for 5 seconds and get back to the old scene. If I load the old scene again, all the data will be lost. It is like game is starting from the beginning. Is there any way to save the scene data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"If I load the old scene again"
means you are calling the FXMLLoader again?
If so, all your old information is lost because you are creating a NEW scene.
Have you tried just hiding the original scene and simply showing it again when you need it?

Comment: yeah I was calling FXMLLoader again. Let me try with hiding the scene.. Btw Thanks..